# substitute for chickpeas in "bean blondies"

Tags: substitutions, dessert

I'm trying to make "[chickpea blondies](http://www.ambitiouskitchen.com/2013/04/flourless-chocolate-chip-chickpea-blondies-with-sea-salt-vegan-gluten-free-healthy/)" However, my brothers won't eat them because chickpeas are estrogenic.

In the recipe, you have to puree the chickpeas, add some peanut butter for strength and taste, and then bake it. So it needs to be relatively firm, sweet or nutty, and hold up in heat. . Is there some other sort of firm bean/food item that could be substituted for the chickpea? They don't have to be beans. I've seen avocados used in recipes like this, but one brother is allergic

Please don't say flour, because making actual brownies defeats the purpose. The fun of it comes from making an  tasty imitation dessert out of unconventional non-dessert ingredients like *beans.

*excepting red beans

Comment: Lima beans might work, except for that nasty thick cover on them. I'd think Navy or Great northern would make a decent substitute.

Comment: And excepting black bean, black eyed peas, and some other beans

Answer (score 3):

I've had great success with black bean brownies. Most recently I tried [this](http://minimalistbaker.com/vegan-gluten-free-black-bean-brownies/) recipe on recommendation from a friend and it turned out quite well! Very rich, great-textured brownies.

The batter is quite thick, though, so make sure your blender/food processor is up to the task!

Comment: I've also made good black bean brownies, but I'm trying to make something that could simulate the vanilla-y cake-y taste of a blondie.  I guess black beans could do that, but the only draw back is the color.

Comment: My mistake - I didn't read the question text as carefully as I should have. I haven't any specific suggestions for blondies but I hope someone else is able offer a better answer.

Comment: *my brothers won't eat them because chickpeas are estrogenic* ...black beans may be considered estrogenic also. It depends on how fussy @kc_m's brothers are.